# How to move a Game Object with his own axes in Unity3D c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hellow everyone.
I woud like to move an Game Object (a tank in this case) down, on his own y axes. But I can't figure how to do it. It's looks very basic but every try I do failed.
So I have this (last line):

```
public void MoveRightOrLeft(float xOffset)
{   
    if (xOffset == 0){
        return;
    }
    RaycastHit2D hitInfo;
    //RaycastHit2D hitInfo2;
    if (xOffset > 0) {
        hitInfo= Physics2D.Raycast (transform.FindChild ("RightExtrem").transform.position, gameObject.transform.up*-1, Mathf.Infinity, DetectableLayerMouvement);
    }else{
        hitInfo= Physics2D.Raycast (transform.FindChild ("LeftExtrem").transform.position, gameObject.transform.up*-1, Mathf.Infinity, DetectableLayerMouvement);
    }
    xOffset *= speed;
    transform.up = hitInfo.normal;

    Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
    newPos += transform.right * xOffset;
    transform.position = newPos;

    // HERE IS THE LINE WHERE I M TRYING
    gameObject.transform.Translate (gameObject.transform.up -new Vector3(0,hitInfo.distance,0));

}
```

I don't get why it doesn't work and how to do it work. Here is a screenshoot of the tanks and the greengizmow are the raycast.
[http://i.imgur.com/aR7nysZ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyM95.png)
Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what's the present, incorrect behaviour? It'd hard to tell with just a static image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) method.

That way, you could move the tank downwards using something like

```
void Update{
    if (movingDown){
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                                                 new Vector3(transorm.postion.x, transorm.position.y - distanceDownwards, transform.position.z), 
                                                 speed);
    }
}
```